# Pandas DataFrame: group and count over multiple group over two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in pandas like this:

```
In[1]: df
Out [1]:
    City         Cluster
0    Paris             A
1    Paris             A
2    Paris             B
3    Paris             B
4    Paris             B
5    Nairobi           C
6    Nairobi           A
7    Nairobi           C
8    Phnom_penh        B
9    Phnom_penh        B
10   Phnom_penh        B
```

I want to count for each cluster/city how many times a city/cluster appears like this:

```
In[2]: df_count
Out[2]:
    Paris    Nairobi    Phnom_penh
A       2          1             0
B       3          0             3
C       0          2             0
```

I tried to use groupby function with count, size ... But no success.

I think groupby function is not the way, but what is the way? There is a pairwise count function? Cross tab function?

Answer (score 0):

I found the function pandas.crosstab which do the work.

```
pandas.crosstab(df['City'], df['Cluster']).T
```

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['Cluster'], df['City'])`.